# Blocking the unwanted Web Traffic

Tags: security, firewall, ip, network-monitoring

There are some trackers most of the times you could see they are running on your PC,
Dependent on the softwares, services, Addons, OPSys, ... much more
some of the major trackers could be 'Google', 'Microsoft' , 'Facebook' , ...
I want to reduce the analyses ! they need and the data which always is passing through the air.

At first the question was :
*How to **block** a dynamic range of **IPs** in **firewalls**,
e.g Norton 360*

Some of the most online hosts :
About 8-10 different IPs which are related to micr0soft,
1e100, qWest, thePlanet, ...

Maybe I don't know a lot about these each.
but would like to here some experts advices on what I want to do.

What I mean (samples)

- 208-44-23-65.dia.static.qwest.net
- 208-44-17-183.dia.static.qwest.net

The different IPs  are shown in the texts used for generating dynamic host names.
The range is big.

The IP and hostname differs any time I log in.

Thanks for the buddies participated in the topic

Comment: This question is too broad, the approach or syntax differs between all firewalls.  `access-list outside_in deny ip 208.44.0.0 255.255.0.0 any` would be the approach on a Cisco ASA firewall.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think it's specific not broad. It could be better for me if you could provide an example in popular firewall softwares (Security Suites). I change some peaces of the question to avoid it's broadness.

Comment: Hello Sypress, please read the [faq], and you'll get a better idea of the types of questions appropriate to this site.  If you have a question about how to do this in a specific firewall, then it meets the "not broad" criteria.

Comment: At first I was looking a generic way, I didn't mention the name cause if you said a way on avast I could do the same in norton. Also that's possible to block some of them via the windows host file. I wanted to get some more generic ideas. cause may be the question need a different answer which not be exactly about blocking an IP Range. Anyway if I have the permission I'll change a question a bit, And want to know that Do other experts suggest any filtering on such a similar IPs or not ? Again thanks remembering

Comment: Your problem will be that these companies use Content Distribution Networks.  This means that the IP addresses change over time, could be anywhere (in any range), and could potentially be used for other services.   It is always best to ask the question based on the problem you are facing, rather than asking a question about an approach you have already decided upon to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can do it is to specify the entire IP range. I'm more concerned as to why you want to block qwest. If you are trying to hide your internet activity from your ISP, this is not the way to do it. Servers in that range may even be name servers, in which case blocking all incoming traffic would cause the web to stop working completely, unless navigating via IP address due to the lack of name resolution.

Comment: I'm as worried as you :D, I know how to block a range but you are right as you said doing this on this range and also some similar ranges will cause some misfunctionality. May be I'm wrong on doing this and that's the reason I'm here to ask and get more consultations. I saw when I disabled even windows update the data is in the air !!! 1e100 as a service of google is also all the time running, there should be a way to stop some of these unwanted data transfer. These are really disgusting when they are without your permission. +1

Comment: If you want to stop services such as windows update completly, you will want to go to Control Panel, Administractive Tools, then Services. Scroll down to Windows Update, right click and go to properties. Hit stop in the properties screen and select disabled from the drop down and hit apply. This will stop all windows update traffic and also stop windows from updating, and therefore leaving your machine vulnerable to attack. You can stop any google related services in that list via the same method. I suspect the google traffic will be from 'Google Update' which links to the google toolbar.

Comment: I know about the Win Upd method, Don't know about google services. and do not have a google toolbar.